# Uncompromised phone with new wallet. Had Bitcoin moved but how

Tags: blockchain.info

So I know what is going to be said my phone is compromised. But hear me out. So I won $1000 dollars worth of Bitcoin. Had it transfered to a brand new wallet. Didn't look or back up the memonic phrase. Only created and transfered. And went to bed. Nobody knew I even won it. 8hrs later it's moved to another new wallet, while I'm asleep. Phones not rooted. Has no malware that I'm aware of. Scanned with several trojan finders, anti-malware programs. Nothing found. The Bitcoin still sits in this wallet it was moved to. No friends, no business partners. I sleep with my phone, it was turned off actually and I have 6 pitbulls. Nobody had physical access to the phone. Next morning turn my phone on. 5 minutes before I do. It's moved. I turned off the phone 1 minute after transaction is completed. It is an app wallet. And with all the security breach's, I'm positive it's not on my side. The app wallet says the same thing over and over. We can't be hacked. Are devs are perfect. Bullshit. Everything is hackable one way or another. devs are human. And mistakes can and will be made. How can I track this transaction, get all the info possible and reverse this transaction? Support with the wallet refuses to even consider this. Says it's my phone. The backup I never made. And even tho I powered off the phone it's my fault, and there's nothing they can do. That someone had to physically have my phone. Powered off? Immediately after transaction? Well noone physically had my phone, no one to have it. No business partners. Now it's conomi wallet. This is the wallet address it's sitting in. 1BppitPsoVtF3NmJRDvvfYKpEjMNU2G2Sp

Help me please

Comment: Did the prizegiver suggest you use a Coinomi wallet? Did they provide you with a link to it?

Comment: Wasn't a prize giver. It was stake casino. The btc still sits in the wallet. I never use a wallet that's suggested anywhere. I've used conomi previously. Trust wallet. I don't trust. New phone, new wallet new playstore download, no root. Antivirus and malware protection in the phone. 16gb 256 gb ram. It's no slouch. And it was turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile wallets are more secure than other wallets(custodial) it means the keys are stored to your device instead of custodial wallets(e.g exchanges) that’s the keys are controlled by third party.

Coinomi wallet keys is stored in your device, are you sure that you download the wallet from an original/trusted website ?

Conclusion:  The funds it’s moved by someone that had access to your mobile phone or access to your keys/seed.

Comment: I fully understand that. I do. But that's not what I asked, yes conomi wallet is on playstore, am I sure it's genuine. Hope so. How ever no other coins on my wallet touched, nothing else taken. No deposits the immediate withdraws nothing. Check the transaction, must use 2fa and password. Please not the obvious reply. Because if my 6 pitbulls are now stealing my crypto. Then I need to know. No root. Checked for malware and Trojans. Android 11

Comment: You should read my answer again.

Comment: So I guess you missed the part where I said I never looked at the backup. And what good does Bitcoin do for a dog. No one has access to my phone or wallet

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to tell what actually has happened. As far as I know, coinomi does not allow you to create a wallet without making a backup, as well as also suggest you create a password for it, maybe you missed something to mention. As far as the malware is concerned if your mobile was really infected then it must be well-encrypted malware which is very hard to find for anti-viruses.